# sql server index rebuild slows first query

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, indexing

Database is SQL 2008R2 Enterprise.

I have an SSIS integration that truncates and loads about 15 million rows in a table each night.  After that happens, I have an Execute SQL Task that rebuilds an index on the table b/c it is severely fragmented after the trunc and load.

The issue I have is the first time a report using that table as a datasource.  The first execution takes a while.  After that first execution however, the report is blazing fast as expected until the next night when the truncate and load and index rebuild happens again.

Any recommendations on what I can do fix the performance on the first query on that table?

Comment: You say report, is this an SSRS report you are referring to?

Comment: yes, it's an ssrs report.  but I guess that part may not be important b/c the stored proc that is the datasource performs the same from the report or run directly in ssms.

Comment: So the same performance is encountered with executing the stored proc immediately after the rebuild regardless of whether it's from SSRS or SSMS/sqlcmd/etc? My initial theory was the SSRS had cycled down due to the 20 minute keep alive cycle it had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running a version of your report (sproc?) immediately following the index rebuild which only does say a `TOP 1` select of whatever dataset, to establish the necessary caching and execution plan, this would "prime" the cache and make the settings optimal without having to run the report in its entirety.

Comment: very smart work around, thank you.  if the stats update recommended by avitus above doesn't work, i will give this a shot.

Comment: looks like this is going to be my solution, it definitely works and was a slick work around.  thanks for the help

Comment: Nice, glad it helped you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

After you rebuild the index try updating the stats to fix your performance issue:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

Comment: interesting, I will give this a shot and see if it works for me.

Comment: i updated the stats for the table used in the datasource and this did not fix that first execution issue described.  was i correct to update the stats for the table?